# Weighted Payment Gateway Rotator

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

So my new mission (lol). I'm looking to create a script that will rotate payment gateways for instance i'll add 5 payment gateways in a database and have to give them a weight all totaling up to 100% just like a load balancer. What is the best way and how should i structure the database to make this work where one gateway gets whatever weight percentage that is set for that payment gateway id. If you could led me in the right direction or have any good tutorials that would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My idea:
Give each gateway a "hits" column. Containing the number of times people used it. And a percentage column-the desired weight for each gateway.
So the table is:
Name: gateways
Columns: Gateway,Hits,Percentage

Then before sending the user the gateway, sum up all of the hits for all of the gateways, then divide the total hits to the hits for every gateway and store the values in an array. The results of the array will actually be the current percentage of the gateways. Then send the gateway with the biggest difference between the desired percentage and the current percentage. In PHP this would look something like this, after connecting to the database:

```
$cur_perc_query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gateways");
$totalhits=0;
while ($cur_get=mysql_fetch_array($cur_perc_query)) {
$totalhits+=$cur_get['Hits'];
}
while ($cur_get=mysql_fetch_array($cur_perc_query)) {
$gate_perc[]=$cur_get['Percentage']-($totalhits/$cur_get['Hits']);
}
$highest=$gate_perc[0];
$gate_number=0;
foreach($gate_perc as $numb => $value) {
if ($highest<$value) { $highest=$value; $gate_number=$numb; }
}
$count=0;
while ($cur_get=mysql_fetch_array($cur_perc_query)) {
if ($count=$gate_number) { $chosen_gate=$cur_get['Gateway']; }
$count++;
}
echo $chosen_gate;
```

I havent tested it but it should work this way.
The other thing you need to do is add 1 to the hits of the current gateway each time a user uses it.
Hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks im gonna try it out and tweak it if need be, thanks for the kick start!

Comment: i think this is off $gate_perc[]=$cur_get['Percentage']-($totalhits/$cur_get['Hits']);   wouldn't it be hits / totalhits to get that gateway percentage?

Comment: you're right - I overlooked that. I was just typing too fast :) It would be like this: $gate_perc[]=$cur_get['Percentage']-(($cur_get['Hits']/$totalhits)*100);
That would be the percentage. Of course, since the variables in php sometimes act as integers-only, you'll need to specify that the result should be a floating point number, since: Lets say we want the percentage of 20 out of 200, thats 20/200=0.1 .. since that's a floating point, PHP might return just 0, then multiply by 100 and still return 0 instead of 10. I think it would be wise to use bcdiv($numb1,$numb2,numb_of_numbers_after_.)

Comment: I suggest you divide using bcdiv everywhere you expect the result will contain a floating point.

Comment: Ok cool and my last quetion is why do you subtract the $cur_get['Percentage']- and the calculated percentage?

Comment: and i changed $highest to this $highest = max($gate_perc); you think this will work as well

Comment: OK nevermind i think i see why you did $highest the way you did, because you need to get the array position